# Why can't you update a value of a nested property in an object directly?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I was playing around in React Native and came across this error. I don't understand why the first snippet throws an error, while the second one runs fine.

This does not work:

```js
let newContent = { ...oldContent }; // <-- oldContent is a 'const'
newContent.value = newValue; // <-- property at 'root level' can be modified
newContent.nested.a = b; // <-- throws 'You attempted to set the key with the value on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.'
```

But this works fine:

```js
let newContent = { ...oldContent };
newContent.value = newValue;
newContent.nested = {
   a: b,
}
```

The value of `nested.a` is defined on `oldContent`.

Is this expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong in the first snippet?

Comment: Cloning doesn't clone nested objects but instead returns references.

Comment: Interesting (linked stackoverflow). I am quite suprised that javascript doesn't offer a simple and clean solution for cloning nested objects.